# PHP/ HTML: Download PDF link working on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using following code

```
<?php
$file = 'COMPANY_PROFILE.pdf';

if (! file) {
    die('file not found'); //Or do something 
} else {
    // Set headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    // Read the file from disk
    readfile($file); 
}
```

This automatically gives a download file prompt and if i use something like this:

```
<a href="COMPANY_PROFILE.pdf" target="_blank" ">Download PDF </a>
```

it opens the PDF in the browser, so how do I fix this issue in a way that file gets downloaded on button click?

Comment: Is this code runs on some kind of event? Please share your proper code. In above code it looks like you are using wrong condition.

Comment: i  just got this code , i  know this condition  says download if it exists how do i detect a click in php ? this is whole working code

Comment: You can do this with an ajax call or by posting something to php. So that you could tell the code that if this event calls then apply this code.

Comment: you mean setting a string in url it can work ? good idea i'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired results by different methods. In this way what you are doing right know you are telling php to look for a file if it doesn't exist just show that file doesn't exit other wise show document that exist.

But what you are looking for should perform on some kind of an event. e.g Button Click.

You can achieve this by these kind of method.

**AJAX Call**

By an ajax call on click on a button to go to this php function.

**Posting PHP**

Either you can post some thing to PHP and in your PHP code you can tell your code if this specific name has been posted then download pdf otherwise not to.

Comment: yes i did setup href="index.php?file=name,pdf" and  then  got this value in $_GET['file'] and in isset used above code

Comment: Good explanation bro